# Run CCAnimation over a sprite - not replace it

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite and i want run some animations, but over the sprite with some alpha in my animation or not.
By example, imagine you have one character (Son Goku) and you want run "aura" animation over it. You will see goku with aura animation.

How you do it ?
For running animation, cocos2d need a ccsprite and replace it when animation running. I can't add this animation to my character sprite.

I have achieved it whith creating "temp" sprite, add animation to temp sprite, add temp sprite as child of character sprite, but I don't like it.
I think there is another better way...

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this without creatimg an additional sprite. But you can incapsulate it. For example, by creating CCNode subclass for your character, which will contain both hero main sprite and animation sprite. In such way you will isolate all animation code inside this class.

Comment: OK, it's strange for me to create additional sprite with one frame of my animation just for running animation. Maybe i will make ccsprite category with one method which return a "CCSprite animated" automatically. In any case, thank you

Comment: Many of my games have CCSprites as children of other sprites, its fairly standard practice, especially for overlaying animations, the advantage means the child of the original sprite moves and rotates with the parent, its very handy. Make a SonGoku subclass of CCSprite, and make it have a CCSprite *aura property ;)